# Multi database query ACCESS and SQL SERVER

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, sql-server-2012

I'm not able to figure out how to make a multi database query usign two diffent ditabase.
The first database is an **ACCESS** mdb database and the second one is a **SQL Server 2012** database.

**I'm using Visual Basic 6**.

The code I'm using is that:

```
ConnectionString1 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=C:\MyDatabase.mdb"
ConnectionString2 = "DSN=ODBC_NAME;UID=user;PWD=password"

SQL = "SELECT tabScheda.sWorkNum FROM tabScheda WHERE codScheda NOT IN" + _
      "  (SELECT ORDERID FROM [" + ConnectionString2 + "].V_PRESETTING_SP_HEADER WHERE MODE = 'TC')"

cn.Open ConnectionString1

Set rc = cn.Execute(SQL)

rc.Close
Set rc = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Please help me :D

Comment: You should connect to single database to execute the query. That database should link to other server and using link server you need to execute the query.

Comment: Could you explain it better please?

Comment: Easiest method is to add the tables needed from SQL as Linked tables in MSAccess.   External Data -> More -> ODBC -> Link -> Machine Data Source -> New

Comment: @AlanWaage is possible to make this link via code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, vaca.  I beleive it is, but I have only ever refreshed an existing link, not created one from scratch.